# what does the presence of an enum keyword as a return type indicate

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, enums

I am currently working with a huge codebase and I came across this statement

```
static enum OPTION_FILE_NUM FileOption(const char *target);
```

Now I am not sure what `enum OPTION_FILE` return type indicate here ? I searched the entire code base for `OPTION_FILE_NUM` type and I could not find anything yet the code compiles fine in Visual Studio. Now when i use the same code in Mingw GCC I get the following error.

```
 error: use of enum 'OPTION_FILE_NUM' without previous declaration
```

My question is what does the above statement indicate ?

Comment: right click on OPTON_FILE_ENUM and choose 'go to definiton'

Comment: Visual studio is not helping in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio as a non standard extension allows forward declaration of enum's (with no size information).

So you are seeing that feature be used here.  It forward declares an enum of name `OPTION_FILE_NUM` and says the function returns it.

As the extension is non-standard, your other compilers complain.

Either inject the proper decl before using it, or if C++11 inject a `enum OPTION_FILE_NUM:int;` If I remember correctly that is what msvc does implicitly.  (amusingly, msvc did not support sized enums forward decl, but only unsized, which is the opposite of what the standard mandates).

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly this:

```
enum OPTION_FILE_NUM {elem1, elem2};

// function that returns OPTION_FILE_NUM
static enum OPTION_FILE_NUM FileOption(const char *target){} 

int main(){}
```

You are declaring a function of which return type is `enum OPTION_FILE_NUM`. You should have the definition somewhere in your code base, or in some header that you're including. Try using an IDE and use the "jump to definition" option, you'll be able to locate the culprit.

Comment: Just wanted to verify that. Looks like I might have to look in external libraries and grep it. Visual studio is not helping in this case

Comment: I can tell you for sure that `OPTION_FILE_NUM` is not a standard C++ object or keyword. So it must be defined somewhere.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. - Marked as answer after timer clears up